# How to create Ambilight for my GMMK keyboard?

Tags: java, keyboard

So I'm trying to display the average color of my screen onto my keyboard.
This is called "Ambilight", there is already code out there that gets me the average screen color, but I'm stuck on the part on how to communicate those colors to my keyboard software so it actually changes the color of my keyboard.
Here is the code of somebody who tried the same thing but with LED strips (Arduino).
Since I am very new to programming I do no understand every single line from the code below. Now I was wondering what do I have to change or what do I have to add to be able to Ambilight my keyboard. 
Here is the software for my keyboard: https://www.pcgamingrace.com/pages/gmmk-software-download ([Download GMMK ISO Keyboard Editor - Compact Size v2.0])

```
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.PortInUseException;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.UnsupportedCommOperationException;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class Ambilight {

//Arduino communication config
public static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;
public static final int TIMEOUT = 2000;

//delay between next color calculations in [ms]
private static final long DELAY = 10;

//leds number on strip
public static final int LEDS_NUM = 30;

//number of leds per section
public static final int LEDS_PER_SECTION = 3;

//we split strip to sections because of performance reasons
public static final int SECTIONS = LEDS_NUM / LEDS_PER_SECTION;

//screen resolution
public static final int X_RES = 1920;
public static final int Y_RES = 1080;

//sections width and height
public static final int SECT_WIDTH = X_RES / SECTIONS;
public static final int SECT_HEIGHT = Y_RES;

//for better performance we do not calculate every pixel,
//but skip some of them
public static final int SECT_SKIP = 10;

// robot to read the data from the screen
private Robot robot;

// arduino communication
private SerialPort serial;
private OutputStream output;
/**
 * init arduino communication
 */
private void initSerial() {
// find the port where teh arduino is connected
CommPortIdentifier serialPortId = null;
Enumeration enumComm = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
while (enumComm.hasMoreElements() && serialPortId == null) {
serialPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) enumComm.nextElement();
}
try {
serial = (SerialPort) serialPortId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
TIMEOUT);
serial.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE, SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
} catch (PortInUseException | UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
/**
 * init the robot
 */
private void initRobot() {
try {
robot = new Robot();
} catch (AWTException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
/**
 * init arduino output
 */

private void initOutputStream() {
try {
output = serial.getOutputStream();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
/**
 * read colors from the screen
 * 
 * @return array with colors that will be send to arduino
 */
private Color[] getColors() {
BufferedImage screen = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(
new Dimension(X_RES, Y_RES)));
Color[] leds = new Color[SECTIONS];
for (int led = 0; led < SECTIONS; led++) {
BufferedImage section = screen.getSubimage(led * SECT_WIDTH, 0, 
SECT_WIDTH, SECT_HEIGHT);
Color sectionAvgColor = getAvgColor(section);
leds[led] = sectionAvgColor;
}
return leds;
}
/**
 * calculate average color for section
 */
private Color getAvgColor(BufferedImage imgSection) {
int width = imgSection.getWidth();
int height = imgSection.getHeight();
int r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
int loops = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < width; x += SECT_SKIP) {
for (int y = 0; y < height; y += SECT_SKIP) {
int rgb = imgSection.getRGB(x, y);
Color color = new Color(rgb);
r += color.getRed();
g += color.getGreen();
b += color.getBlue();
loops++;
}
}
r = r / loops;
g = g / loops;
b = b / loops;
return new Color(r, g, b);
}
/**
 * Send the data to Arduino
 */
private void sendColors(Color[] leds) {
try {
output.write(0xff);
for (int i = 0; i < SECTIONS; i++) {
output.write(leds[i].getRed());
output.write(leds[i].getGreen());
output.write(leds[i].getBlue());
}
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

//Main Loop
private void loop() {
while (true) {
Color[] leds = getColors();
sendColors(leds);
try {
Thread.sleep(DELAY);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
Ambilight ambi = new Ambilight();
ambi.initRobot();
ambi.initSerial();
ambi.initOutputStream();
ambi.loop();
}
}
```

Comment: That all depends on the keyboard. Is there an API for it? Or some controller software you can interface with? You need to research that first. Maybe ask at [gaming.se].

Comment: @JohnnyMopp The user posted the question on Arqade, but it's off-topic there. Technical programming questions is out of our scope

Comment: @Wondercricket Ok. I just figured someone at Arqade might have already done something like this. My bad.